# I am observing that once a mat-chip-option has been manually selected/deselected, it does not respond correctly to a change in its bound variable

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have provided an example where I have < mat-chip-option selected="testState" > and I two buttons, one to set testState=true and the other to set testState=false. The issue that I am seeing is that I can programmatically select/deselect an  as much as I want. But once a user manually clicks on the chip, you cannot programmatically change the selection state to the other value (ie. if user clicked select, cannot programmatically deselect, and vice versa) until you programmatically set it to the same state that the user click it to.

I provided three use cases:

- Use Case 1 - programmatically changing (establish that it works)
- Use Case 2 - manually select option
- Use Case 3 - manually desselet option

Here are the use cases:

**Use Case #1:**

- Starts with Option unchecked (deselected)
- Set Selected True and Option gets checked (selected) - This is expected behavior
- Set Selected False and Option gets unchecked (deselected) - This is expected behavior

**Use Case #2:**

- Starts with Option unchecked (deselected)
- Set Selected True and Option gets checked (selected) - This is expected behavior
- Set Selected False and Option gets unchecked (deselected) - This is expected behavior
- Manually select Option and Option get checked (selected) - This is expected behavior
- Set Selected False and Option stays checked (selected) *** Expected behavior is that the Option would become unselected. You can try to set to false as much as you want, but it wont.
- Set Selected True and Option stay checked (selected) - This is expected behavior
- Set Selected False and Option gets unchecked (deselected) - This is expected behavior

**Use Case #3:**

- Starts with Option unchecked (deselected)
- Set Selected True and Option gets checked (selected) - This is expected behavior
- Set Selected False and Option gets unchecked (deselected) - This is expected behavior
- Set Selected True and Option gets checked (selected) - This is expected behavior
- Manually select Option and Option get unchecked (deselected) - This is expected behavior
- Set Selected True and Option stays unchecked (deselected) *** Expected behavior is that the Option would become selected. You can try to set to true as much as you want, but it wont.
- Set Selected False and Option stays unchecked (deselected) - This is expected behavior
- Set Selected True and Option gets checked (selected) - This is expected behavior

Is this expected behavior?

Here is my app.component.html:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="setState(true)">Set Selected True</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="setState(false)">Set Selected False</button>
    </p>
    <mat-chip-listbox>
        <mat-chip-option [selected]="testState">
            Option
        </mat-chip-option>
    </mat-chip-listbox>
    <p>
        Button is {{testState}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  testState: boolean = false;

  setState(newState: boolean) {
    this.testState = newState;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if the above behavior is expected or not, but I did determine how to have the user action update the component property as expected and generate the desired behavoir.

You need to handle the SelectionChange event:

In the template, make this change

> <mat-chip-option [selected]="testState" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">

And in the component, add the appropriate handler:

> onSelectionChange(event: any) { this.testState = event.selected; }